# .net mvc - deploy application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, build, deployment

I have a .net mvc 2 application.

What is the usual way to hand this application to our customer (similar like war file would be)?

Can I just zip the publish-ed version of the app? Or are there any smarter ways to do it, and better ways to get there then to do a publish from VS?

Answer (score 0):

Publish + zip + copy is called [Xcopy deployment](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;326355&x=12&y=16) and is a recommended way of deploying web applications, including ASP.NET MVC web applications. It works great for anything that doesn't rely on anything that isn't included in the web application folder.

ASP.NET MVC 1.0 required a separate install which made it slighly less fool proof.